# Drawer react native map items

Tags: reactjs, react-native

the CustomDrawerContentt component receives the ...props from the parent component.
the parent component is composed of a Drawer.Navigator and a Drawer.Screen, the props that are sent to the child component are the screen of each Drawer.Screen.
what I want to do is instead of passing a ... props from the parent component, I want to directly pass these screens to the CustomDrawerContentt component. ie replace ... props with myScreen.

**myScreens**:
views: {
Home: AdminView,
CrudCategories: CrudCategories,
CrudItems: CrudItems,
ListItems: ListItems
},

**CustomDrawerContentt Component: (child component)**

```
      function CustomDrawerContentt(props) {
      return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>

          <DrawerItemList {...props} />

          <DrawerItem
            label="Close drawer"
            onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}
          />
          <DrawerItem
            label="Logged"
            onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
          />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
      )
    }
```

**App return:**

```
    return (
      userRoutes
        ?
        <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerPosition='right'
          drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContentt {...props} linksSidebar={userRoutes.sidebar}
          />}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Inicio" component={RoutesModals} />

        </Drawer.Navigator>
        :
        <LoadingScreens />
    );
```

I have tried it before and it has worked for me, but now that I come across ... props the console gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined"

for example this component, where **userRoutes.views** has the same structure mentioned above (myScreens) and it has worked perfectly for me.

```
    const RoutesViews = () => {
      return (
        <ViewsStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          {Object.entries({          
            ...(userRoutes.views),
          }).map(([name, component, index]) => (
            <ViewsStack.Screen key={name} name={name} component={component} options={name == 'Home' ? { headerShown: false } : { headerShown: true }} />
          ))}
        </ViewsStack.Navigator>
      )
    }
```

I would like to know how I do it instead of passing <DrawerItemList {...props} /> can I pass <DrawerItemList {myScreens} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Redux to store whatever you want and access it in Child Component. It will be easy to handle.